How can I provide localized Qute MessageBundle values at runtime?
Using Qute Message Bundles, how can I provide message values at runtime?
For example, I have values stored in a database that can be changed at any time. Whenever my application obtains a message from a message bundle, I would want to check if the key exists in the database, and use the respective value if it does.
My values should have precedence over values provided via other means (eg, defaults and properies files).

To provide message values at runtime using Qute Message Bundles in Quarkus, you can use the MessageBundles interface which allows you to dynamically supply values or read it from db or user provided value that can override the ones defined in properties files or defaults.
Eg.
import io.quarkus.qute.i18n.MessageBundle;

@MessageBundle
public interface MyMessages {
    String hello(String name);
}

Usage:
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    MessageBundles messageBundles;

    public void greet(String name) {
        MyMessages myMessages = messageBundles.get(MyMessages.class);
        // Providing runtime value
        String message = myMessages.hello(name);
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}

